# combining same css style for 2 different browser

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is it possible to combine same style on different browser. I do understand that we could apply same css style for different tags like e.g

```
p , span{
background: red;
}
```

I would like to shorten my css code for

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar { 
    background:#cbccce;
}
 progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background:#cbccce;
}
```

this is what ive tried and but it seems not to be working.

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar , progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background:#cbccce;
}
```

ve tried searching but i couldnt find an aswer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You cannot combine the "**vendor prefixes**" together.

But you can use developers tools to auto-generate them like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or you can use CSS preprocessor `SASS` `LESS` to shorten your `css` code

> **What is a CSS preprocessor?**
>   
>   
>   A CSS preprocessor is a scripting language that extends CSS by allowing developers to  write code in one language and then compile it into CSS. Sass is perhaps the most  popular preprocessor around right now, but other well-known examples include Less and Stylus.